# Cómo quedaría el patrón si quiero que solo este tipo de registros aparezcan en la consola y descarte al resto en python

Tags: python

Mi registro tal cual es así:

```
#######Daniel  Juarez  Lopez #######1952######ENERO#####24####1345698734#####TOTAL 34500
```

Pero al realizar el patrón me da errores, tengo la duda de como sería
Yo puse este patrón pero me da errores

```
mi_patron = r'W{7}\w{3,15}\s\w{3,15}\s\w{3,15}\s\W{7}\d{4}\W{6}\w{4,10}\W{5}\d{1,2}\W{4}\d{10}\W{5}\TOTAL\s\d{5}'
```

Comment: Por favor, reedite su pregunta. No se puede ver nada

Comment: ´´´\TOTAL´´´ no debería tener ese ´´´\´´´ deberia ser ´´´...\W{5}TOTAL...´´´, porque tomará ´´´\T´´´ y eso no hay en regex.

Answer (score 0):

¿Es obligatorio usar regex? Si no, en vez de usar un patrón tan complejo, por qué no le haces un pre-tratamiento sin expresiones regulares:

```py
p = "#######Daniel  Juarez  Lopez #######1952######ENERO#####24####1345698734#####TOTAL 34500"
result = [x.strip() for x in p.split('#') if x != '']
```

La variable `result` tendrá:

```py
['Daniel  Juarez  Lopez', '1952', 'ENERO', '24', '1345698734', 'TOTAL 34500']
```

Si quieres, puedes mapear una función (que tendrás que hacer) para que quite los espacios extras de algunos elementos, como el nombre. De hecho, podrías hacerlo directamente en la comprehension, en vez de `x.strip()` reemplazarlo por `mi_funcion(x)`.